# Возвращение в активити, по истечению таймера

Tags: java, android

По истечению таймера пользователь автоматически должен возвращаться в активити(`ResultActivity` к примеру). Вот код

```
@Override
public void onFinish() {
    times.setText("Время вышло");
}

@Override
public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    long millis = millisUntilFinished;
    String hms = String.format(
            "%02d:%02d:%02d",
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis),
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis)
                    - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS
                    .toHours(millis)),
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millis)
                    - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS
                    .toMinutes(millis)));
    System.out.println(hms);
    times.setText(hms);
}
```

Comment: откуда он должен возвращаться?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

Я так понимаю вы работаете с  countdowntimer. При окончании счетчика сработает

```
onFinish()
```

Добавьте туда логику или возврата:

```
public void onFinish() {
times.setText("Время вышло");
onBackPressed();
}
```

Или так:

```
public void onFinish() {
times.setText("Время вышло");
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ResultActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
}
```